# spam mail with webappscanner@mcafeesecure.com content

Tags: php, forms, security

hi i have website where user can request catalog.For that i am using a form with fields

1. Company Name
2. Email
3. Contact Address
4. State:
5. City
6. Post Code:
7. Phone Number:

But for the past two days i am getting around 190 spam mail with all the fields containing webappscanner@mcafeesecure.com

But my form was validated using php and javascript later, and also set time limit.

eg:user can only send one request,for the second request he has to wait for 5min.

Here comes the code

```
    if($_SESSION['time']==""){
        $_SESSION['time'] = time();
        $mins = 7;
    }else{
        $currentTime = time();
        $date_created = $_SESSION['time'];
        $mins = (abs($date_created - $currentTime)) / 60;
    }

if($mins>5){
   //Send mail
   $_SESSION['time'] = time();
}else{
 To prevent against spam requests, please wait 5 minutes before making a second request. 
}
```

Can any one help me to fix this.

Comment: We could if you showed us some code.

Comment: just simple html and php code ....with phpmailer

Comment: and sorry i am not authorized to share code :(

Comment: I am not asking you to share all the code you have there, just the parts you use for time limitation, or an example of what you already have.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. The spam bot may simply be intelligent enough to surpass your protection. Are you asking about how to strengthen the protection, or is the time limit not working?

Comment: Why not use any of the commonly available anti-spam measures, such as CAPTCHA?

Or, if you don't want to bother with that,  I've seen people use simple requests at the end of a form, like "Please enter the word cat into the box below."

Comment: @pekka i have to strengthen the protection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avert spam is to introduce a [Captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captcha) that has to be solved in order to submit the form.

Further you can also restrict the timeout by IP address instead of session. But this would require an additional overhead of cleaning out the stale IP address information from your persistent storage (such as database or file). You can also look at banning ip addresses, if they hammer your form too frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Spam bots don't follow the same rules as browsers so this one probably just ignoring any cookies you send. Based on the code you posted it looks like the test passes also when there is no existing session. You should also check that a session exists before allowing the user to send the form. (This will of course affect also legitimate users who have cookies disabled.)

But since mcafeesecure.com seems to be a legitimate site, it's possible that this is a case of a misconfigured security app (the "webappscanner" part hints at that possibility).

Comment: is there any way to prevent spam mails

Comment: Not 100%. If requiring a valid session is not an option, you can add CAPTCHA. For this particular case you could check if all data in every field is the same and discard if they are, or block if they contain that email address, or block the IP address they're coming from if it's always the same.

Comment: Also, if you use server side validation that allows an email address in the post code and phone number fields you might want to revise that as well.